# Android studio how to query

Tags: sqlite, dictionary, android-studio, medical

Hi guys i'am new in developing android applications and currently creating a dictionary that can detect a symptom by search function. For example the user search a cough the application must display the diseases related to the symptom.

I'am sqlite database, my database design is good now because i have table of symptom, illness and another for joint table to be able to do a many to many relationship.

1) My problem is how can i get the table in my existing database?
2) How can i do a nested sql search containing of two queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create your own Sqlite database and query it. You must make 2 query instead of only one. Some reference:

https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Local-Databases-with-SQLiteOpenHelper
http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Best regards